# PHP waiting for correct response with cURL

Tags: php, curl, sleep

I don't know how to make this.
There is an XML Api server and I'm getting contents with cURL; it works fine. Now I have to call the `creditCardPreprocessors` state. It has 'in progress state' too and PHP should wait until the progess is finished. I tried already with sleep and other ways, but I can't make it. This is a simplified example variation of what I tried:

```
function process_state($xml){
  if($result = request($xml)){
  // It'll return NULL on bad state for example
    return $result;
  }
  sleep(3);
  process_state($xml);
}
```

I know, this can be an infite loop but I've tried to add counting to exit if it reaches five; it won't exit, the server will hang up and I'll have 500 errors for minutes and Apache goes unreachable for that vhost.

EDIT:

Another example

```
$i = 0;
$card_state = false;

// We're gona assume now the request() turns back NULL if card state is processing TRUE if it's done

while(!$card_state && $i < 10){
    $i++;
    if($result = request('XML STUFF')){
        $card_state = $result;
        break;
    }
    sleep(2);
}
```

Comment: Would PHP `break` help you in any way?

Comment: I think you are probably running out of memory because of recursion

Comment: Nope, tried, not beraking, tried with exit too, no exit at all. Tried in a sleep while loop where the request is the condition, and i noly allowed it to run 10 times, no exit at all...

Comment: @vortextangent i have 512mb memory limit on this server, and no, a don't, it only does 10 request at this point... that not that much even for curl...

Comment: could you post some of `request()`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GevzLAxT

Answer (score 2):

The recursive method you've defined could cause problems depending on the response timing you get back from the server.  I think you'd want to use a while loop here.  It keeps the requests serialized.

```
$returnable_responses = array('code1','code2','code3'); // the array of responses that you want the function to stop after receiving
$max_number_of_calls = 5; // or some number

$iterator = 0;
$result = NULL;
while(!in_array($result,$returnable_responses) && ($iterator < $max_number_of_calls)) {
    $result = request($xml);
    $iterator++; 
}
```

Comment: Tried already exactly the same. It's still hanging up. One request just works fine...

Comment: @wintercounter You may want to look into the code that executes the cURL call. It may not be the loop. Is it closing the curl resource or something?

Comment: @wintercounter can you edit the main question with that code?

Comment: Thats just a simple curl request, nothing else... But i added another example which is not working